# There are no compatible JREs installed in the workspace. Add library > JRE system library...nothing

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am getting this error when trying to run a project in Eclipse.

> Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.6. There are no
>   compatible JREs installed in the workspace.

Now this error is documented in quite a few places and have tried to fix it by going to project properties > Java build path > librarys tab > add library > JRE system library...and this is where I can't go any further. When I click 'next' it does absolutely nothing, doesn't change page. The first time I tried I did get an error saying 'null...something'.

Some possible useful info

- I'm using an early macbook. 10.6.8
- Tying javac -version into
- terminal returns javac 1.6.0_65 which javac returns usr/bin/javac
- Using Eclipse Juno

So I assume JRE + JDK is installed. Any help would be most appreciated! I've been trying to fix this for hours now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command terminal and run

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

The output from that command is where you should set eclipse's JRE_HOME.

Example output

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: I tried this and got /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
I then went to preferences > Installed JRE and tried to add it manually but it didn't like the 1.6.0.jdk file so I typed in the directory and got the notification saying " The home directory does not exist."

Comment: AH ha! I accidently added a space. :D awesome thank you. Although I've no idea what to add now it looks like a breakthough. I've now got a huge list /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home /System/Library/Framework/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Try making your window bigger, it's a long path but it must exist. Try and cd to it on the command line; `cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home) && pwd`

Comment: I've got a list but not sure what I need to do now. Here a pic http://imgur.com/2uvYqZR